# Email template using XSLT

Tags: xslt

HI all,
   I have an XML with the different email bodies. I am using xslt to prepare an email template for sending these emails. I also want to include `<subject>` tag to the xml so that the email is more maintainable.I am using spring to send mail. I need to set the body ans subject of the mail. Body of the mail i am setting by using xslt transformation. I want to set the subject too.Please help me out if you have any idea!! I don't want to use xml parsing just for setting subject.Is there any way i can get the subject value using xslt??

here is my xml:

```
<mailMessage>
    <mail type="pinReset">
        <subject>Regarding account pin reset</subject>
        <body>
            <prefix>Hello User You have initiated a pin reset Please click
                on the link below to reset your pin</prefix>
            <suffix>Thank you</suffix>
        </body>
    </mail>
    <mail type="emailUpdate">
        <subject>Regarding account email update</subject>
        <body>
            <prefix>emailupdated</prefix>
            <suffix>thank u</suffix>
        </body>
    </mail>
    <mail type="failureCount">
        <subject>Regarding account unsuccessful login</subject>
        <body>
            <prefix>failureCount</prefix>
            <suffix>thank u</suffix>
        </body>
    </mail>
</mailMessage>
```

I want to fetch the subject separately.

Comment: maybe you should include the xslt

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second, very simple XSLT template that only outputs the subject line.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.Is there any mechanism to reuse the same xsl for subject too?

Comment: I wouldn't complicate the XSL with a mode switch, as outputting the body or the subject are completely seperate things. A seperate file for the subject should be about one line.

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass the string value for the subject, and the mail type as parameters** to the XSLT transformation, and the transformation can be written in such a way as to produce the whole email message.